# How to modify the size of Flash stage programmatically

Tags: actionscript-3, flash

Initially I set the stage width 500 and height 400. After make a file, now I want it to be  700*500 and I want to show  all content in stage. How can I achieve this?
Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

If it's a website you're creating you can programmatically control its size via call through a class called ExternalInterface which in turn calls JavaScript-functions. JavaScript can then be used to resize the embedded flash object.

You can find another post about this here: [How can I resize a swf during runtime to have the browser create html scrollbars?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32871/how-can-i-resize-a-swf-during-runtime-to-have-the-browser-create-html-scrollbars)

Comment: There are a number of ways as the above link shows - but using javascript and an external interface works great.  The only issue is that resizing the flash app could effect the layout on the page and you'll need to take that into consideration.